# How to write one SQL query based on two similar queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database

I have first SQL query:

```
SELECT cias.*
FROM catalog_investors_advanced_search AS cias
INNER JOIN organizations AS o
      ON o.name = cias.name 
      AND cias."entityType" = 'investment-firm'
INNER JOIN investments AS i 
      ON i."entityId" = o.id 
      AND i."entityType" = o."entityType"
ORDER BY i."createdAt" DESC;
```

And second one:

```
SELECT cias.*
FROM catalog_investors_advanced_search AS cias
INNER JOIN persons AS p
      ON p."firstName" || ' ' || p."lastName" = cias.name 
      AND cias."entityType" = 'investor'
INNER JOIN investments AS i 
      ON i."entityId" = p.id 
      AND i."entityType" = p."entityType"
ORDER BY i."createdAt" DESC;
```

They have a similar implementation, how can I write one SQL query based on this two similar queries?

I have seen solutions with "JOIN ALL" it works but I think there might be a more optimized way where I don't have to repeat two queries like join two conditions in one query.

Comment: Please add sample data and expected result.

Comment: I guess you are looking for union all not join all

Answer (score 0):

I would `union` all the investors and investment firms in a CTE first and then `join` the result to the `catalog_investor_advanced_search` and `investment` tables.  It would look something like this:

```
with names as (
  select id, 'investment-firm' as entity_type, name
    from organizations 
  union all
  select id, 'investor' as entity_type,
         "firstName" || ' ' || "lastName" as name
    from persons  
)
select cias.*
  from catalog_investors_advanced_search AS cias
  join names n
    on (n.name, n.entity_type) = (cias.name, cias."entityType")
  join investments i 
    on (i."entityId", i."entityType") = (n.id, n.entity_type)
 order by i."createdAt" desc;
```